# WKWebView scroll back will add a blank UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I used WKWebView by follow way:

```
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
self.webView.UIDelegate = self;
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;
[self.webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"estimatedProgress" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];

self.progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.webView.frame.size.width, 1.0)];
self.progressView.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.progressView];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.rootURL]];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

I set the allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures in delegate:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didCommitNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation {
if (webView.backForwardList.backItem) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = YES;
} else {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = NO;
}
if (self.webView.subviews.count > 1) {
    NSLog(@"有遮盖");
    [self.webView.subviews.lastObject removeFromSuperview];
}
```

}

when I load a url, and navigation to another url, then I scroll go back, the webView will cover a blank view:
[image]

and view hierarchy:

[image]

Why?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the changes of `webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures` during navigation. I don't know why it result this empty UIView, but remove it when webView is navigating will fix the issue.

If you what you want is swipe right to go back in webView, or pop view controller when webView can't go back, You can set this only in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = YES
```

and when webView is navigating, change navigationController only.

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = !webView.canGoBack
```

Maybe it's because when navigationController's gesture recognizer has higher priority to webView's gestures, (or when webView.canGoBack is false, webView's gesture won't recognize, not sure).